# Merging Branches with Jenkins and SVN

Tags: svn, jenkins, version-control

This seems like it should be a fairly straight-forward task, but I'm having difficulty in figuring out how to do it.

Basically, I just want a simple Jenkins job that when triggered, will checkout my "Stable" SVN branch, compare that branch to an "Integration" SVN branch, and then merge in any changes into the Stable branch and execute any unit/integration tests.

Essentially, when the job is triggered, I want it to make my Stable branch mirror my Integration branch exactly.

Does anyone know of an available Jenkins plugin that can do this, or have any guidance on how I can do this?

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: Would a command like this possibly do what I need?


`svn merge --accept=theirs-full`

Comment: @Chiefwarpaint- it sounds like that would work, but be very careful with automated merges.  If your integration branch isn't *completely* up to date with the stable branch *at all times*, then the auto-merge may do nasty things (break the build, overwrite changes, etc).  Some changes, like adding a file to 'stable' but not 'integration', won't get cleaned up by a merge command alone.